# How to realize a navigation through a tag cloud in MySQL

Tags: mysql, optimization, methods, tags, tag-cloud

I want to write a web application to order my photos. Instead of putting them into categories, I want to add tags to certain pictures. I thought of having 2 tables, one for the images:

```
uniqueID   imagename
1          photo1.jpg
2          photo2.jpg
3          photo3.jpeg
4          pic4.jpeg
```

and one table for the tags:

```
ID         tag
1          California
1          Peter
1          beach
2          California
2          L.A.
2          Peter
3          California
3          Susan
4          Kansas
4          Claudia
```

After starting the application the tags are shown in a size accoring to the number of occurences in the database. When I click on a tag (e.g. "California") all the remaining tags of images, that also have the selected tag should be shown on the next page (here: "Peter", "beach", "L.A.", "Susan" but NOT "Kansas" and "Claudia"). When I afterwards click for example on the tag "peter" all the remaining tags of photo 1 and 2 should be shown ("beach", "L.A.").

Is it possible to realize those two things with a single query?

1. Select image-names from the image table, that have all selected tags in the the tag-table
2. Select all remaining tags and their COUNT() for those images (IDs) that also have the selected tags in the tag-table.

Thanks for your help

Sven

Answer (score 0):

For 1) You must use a SELECT query with JOINS. For example:

```
SELECT     *
FROM       images i
INNER JOIN categories c
        ON i.id = c.id
```

For 2) I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean by remaining tags.

Comment: I agree with the INNER JOIN, but I don't know how I have to cosntruct the WHERE clause. It must be something like `... WHERE tag='California' && tag='Peter' ` if I want to have all Images that are tagged with "California" and "Peter". But since all the tags are in the same column, there will never be an an entry that can have both tags (there is only one tag-column!).

Comment: **remaining tags** Every Image has for example 3 tags. When I selected two tags (e.g. "California" and "Peter") I want to get "beach", "L.A." as a result from the table above ("L.A." is the "remaining tag" from image 2 and "beach" is the "remaining tag" from image 1) The "remaining tags" are used to calculate the tag-cloud for all images that have the tags "California" and "Peter". For example the Tag "Susan" should not appear in the new tag cloud, since Image3 is not tagged with "Peter" (only with "California").